# Using custom dependency property in style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, wpf-controls

I have a custom button control with a custom property `IsPlaying`.

```
internal class PlayPauseButton : Button
{
    public bool IsPlaying
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(IsPlayingProperty);
        set => SetValue(IsPlayingProperty, value);
    }

    public readonly static DependencyProperty IsPlayingProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(IsPlaying), typeof(bool), typeof(PlayPauseButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
}
```

I want to bind to that property from its style. I want to show different images which depend on the `IsPlaying` flag value.

```
<Style TargetType="c:PlayPauseButton">
    <Setter Property="IsPlaying" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Image Width="100" Height="100" Visibility="{TemplateBinding IsPlaying, Converter={c:InverseBoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
                        ...
                    </Image>
                    <Image Width="100" Height="100" Visibility="{TemplateBinding IsPlaying, Converter={c:BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
                        ...
                    </Image>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I use the control like this:

```
<c:PlayPauseButton Width="200" Height="100" IsPlaying="{Binding Player.IsPlaying}"/>
```

But I have got a problem with the style. I can't bind to the `IsPlaying` property. You can see below error message:

> "Failed to create 'DependencyProperty' based on text 'IsPlaying.': line number '10' and line position '75'."

Comment: As a note, it might be more convenient to set the Source property of a single Image element by a Style with a Trigger on the IsPlaying property. You would not need any Binding Converters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the [`TargetType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.controltemplate.targettype?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) of the [`ControlTemplate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.controltemplate?view=windowsdesktop-6.0), otherwise the property cannot be resolved in the `TemplateBinding`.

```
ControlTemplate TargetType="c:PlayPauseButton">
```

An alternative is to use a [relative source binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) to the [templated parent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.relativesource.templatedparent?view=windowsdesktop-6.0).

```
<ControlTemplate>
   <Grid>
      <Image Width="100" Height="100" Visibility="{Binding IsPlaying, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={c:InverseBoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
          <!-- ... -->
      </Image>
      <Image Width="100" Height="100" Visibility="{Binding IsPlaying, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={c:BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
          <!-- ... -->
      </Image>
   </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```